# Pixel Bender alternative?

Tags: opencl, pixel-bender, compute-shader

Is there an alternative to the now abandoned Pixel Bender? A framework where I can focus on scripting the core logic and don't have to worry about image I/O, GUI or low level shader code. A GPU based solution would be best because I'd like to use it for calculation heavy tasks like distance field generation where a CPU would be too slow.

Comment: What is your language preference?  Some scripting languages have good OpenCL bindings.

Comment: I'm comfortable with C#, Lua and Python but any kind of documented, higher level language would be fine.

Comment: While not exactly the solution you want, perhaps Python will be the easiest.  PyOpenCL is pretty easy to use and removes tons of bioler plate code.  If your GUI is primarily for displaying plots of results or processed images, matplotlib could help.  There are also several image I/O functions built into matplotlib.